# Angular-ui ui-router - using multiple nested views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying out the nested views feature of ui-router plugin, but faced the issue I don't know how to solve.
The code that shows the problem can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/3c9h7/1/ :

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

  app.config(function($stateProvider) {
    return $stateProvider.state('root', {
      template: "<div class='top' ui-view='viewA'></div><div class='middle' ui-view='viewB'></div>"
    }).state('root.step1', {
      url: '',
      views: {
        'viewA': {
          template: '<h1>View A</h1>'
        }
      }
    }).state('root.step1.step2', {
      url: '/step2',
      views: {
        'viewB': {
          template: '<h1>View B</h1>'
        }
      }
    });
  });

  app.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
      $state.transitionTo('root.step1.step2');
    }
  ]);

<div ng-app='myApp' ui-view ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
</div>
```

So, the code activates "root.step1.step2" state by using $state.go method(https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options)
According to ui-router documentation:

> When the application is in a particular state—when a state is
>   "active"—all of its ancestor states are implicitly active as well.

So, I expect that "root.step1" and "root" will be active and it works as expected, but "viewB" is not filled with the template as you can see in jsfiddle sample : the top viewA(root.step1) is OK, but the middle viewB(root.step1.step2) is empty.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation says:

> Child states will load their templates into their parent's ui-view.

So there should be a `ui-view='viewB'` inside the viewA template, since the parent state of `root.step1.step2` is `root.step1`. Or the viewB should be one of the views of `root.step1`, and there should be no `root.step1.step2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to solve the problem by using the absolute view name viewB@root in the root.step1.step2 state: http://jsfiddle.net/3c9h7/2/ But your suggestion was really helpful to figure it out.