# $state.go not working with 3rd-level nested state (using Ionic tabs / AngularUI)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use `$state.go` to switch between tabs in an Ionic (+AngularJS UI Router) application, but I can't make it work with a sub-sub-state (*state.substate.subsubstate*). It actually works fine when moving to a sub-state (*state.substate*).

Here's what I mean: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jykmi?editors=101

Pressing the "Tab2" button neither works nor throws an error. Nonetheless, replacing the `ng-click="goToState('tabs.tab2.home1')"` (in line 25) with `ui-sref="tabs.tab2.home1"` or `href="#/tabs/tab2/home1"`, works perfectly. Here's an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DIxhC?editors=101

Even using `ng-click="goToState('tabs.tab2')"` would work, though that's not the intended target state.

I've found other similar questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818515/angularjs-nested-states-3-level) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719790/angular-ui-ui-router-using-multiple-nested-views)) but I don't think they had the same problem.

Does anybody know if `$state.go` should work with 3rd-level nested states?. Is the problem in my code?.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Regards,
  Rafa.

Comment: There's some discussion still going on in the ionic forum: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/bug-in-tabbar-with-nested-states/791/

Comment: This seems to be a bug AFAIK. I've also found that transition to "child" states doesn't 100% always work properly, either.

Answer (score 1):

As `ui-sref="tabs.tab2.home1"` internally use `$state.go` and as you said `ui-sref="tabs.tab2.home1"` works.

My answer is yes : `$state.go()` should work with 3rd-level nested states.

I actually use it in my own projet with no problems (but without ionic tabs)

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry I don't have enough reputations to add a comment.

I got the exactly same problem as you do: href or ui-sref works fine while ng-click with $state.go has no effect(the address in browser changed correctly but the view remains unredirected). I solved this problem by simply use them both at the same time:

In html:

```
ui-sref="tabs.tabs2.home" + ng-click="goHome()"
```

or

```
href="#/tabs/tabs2/home" + ng-click="goHome()"
```

In controller js:

```
$scope.goHome = function(){
    $state.go('tabs.tabs2.home');
    // or, location.path works fine too:
    // $location.path('/tabs/tabs2/home');
}
```

I don't know the reason, so this is only a workaround